# What does "OFT" stand for?

Tags: gdal

What does "OFT" stand for?

I'm getting the message "Invalid OFT field name given" in a Python program that uses GDAL, and before I debug it, I'd like to know what it means.

Comment: `OpenGIS Field Type`, though it doesn't fit that well in this error message. For GDAL, check [this](https://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/Constants%20(OFT).html)